# Python: How to copy a file via SSH and paramiko without sftp

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I want to copy a file in python(3.4) using the paramiko library.

My approach:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(192.168.1.1, 22, root, root)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(local_file, remote_file)
sftp.close()
```

The error I get:

```
EOF during negotiation
```

The problem is that the connected system doesn't use sftp.

So is there a way to copy a file without using sftp?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scp` to send files, and `sshpass` to pass password.

```
import os

os.system('sshpass  -p "password" scp local_file root@192.168.1.?:/remotepath/remote_file')
```

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way in paramiko. Otherwise I'll have to do it like you suggested it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in [`paramiko.Transport`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport) layer and create your own [`Channel`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel):

```
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('192.168.1.1', 22, 'root', 'root')

    transport = ssh.get_transport()
    with transport.open_channel(kind='session') as channel:
        file_data = open('local_data', 'rb').read()
        channel.exec_command('cat > remote_file')
        channel.sendall(file_data)
```